# concatenate three variable values into single value in r

Tags: r

I have three variables. My intention is to concatenate three variables into one variable
for that I have used cat function for concatenate three variables but it was displaying values correctly,but I'm getting spaces in between the values. Here I don't want spaces in between the values while making a concatenation.

Comment: Did you try `paste` or `paste0`?

Comment: Did you try goolging "concatenate r"? I don't know how you could have missed `paste/paste0`.

Comment: paste0 function is solved my problem - Thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little more concise than @Duna's suggestion would be the following:

```
## @Duna's sample data
dd = data.frame(x = letters[1:5], y = 1:5, 
                z = c("this", "could", "work", "for", "you!"))

do.call(paste0, dd)
# [1] "a1this"  "b2could" "c3work"  "d4for"   "e5you!"
```

The following would also work:

```
do.call(paste, c(dd, sep = ""))
with(dd, paste(x, y, z, sep = ""))
with(dd, paste0(x, y, z))
```

And, for variety:

```
with(dd, sprintf("%s%s%s", x, y, z))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

```
 as.character(interaction(dd,sep=""))
 #[1] "a1this"  "b2could" "c3work"  "d4for"   "e5you!"
```

Or `paste2` from `library(qdap)`

```
 library(qdap)
 paste2(dd,sep="")
 #[1] "a1this"  "b2could" "c3work"  "d4for"   "e5you!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as **Ananda** suggested!
Let say you have:

```
dd = data.frame(x = letters[1:5], y = 1:5, z = c("this", "could", "work", "for", "you!"))

dd

  x y     z
1 a 1  this
2 b 2 could
3 c 3  work
4 d 4   for
5 e 5  you!
```

then

```
dd$w = paste(dd$x, paste(dd$y, dd$z, sep=""),sep="")
```

so you get

```
dd
  x y     z       w
1 a 1  this  a1this
2 b 2 could b2could
3 c 3  work  c3work
4 d 4   for   d4for
5 e 5  you!  e5you!
```